# How to trigger browserAction popup of chrome extension from page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know how to open the popup of my own extension out of the content script of a page?
Somehow like the Chomecast (Google Cast) Extension does if you are on youtube and click on the cast button in the bottom right corner of a video on the youtube page.

I hope you have an idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot*. The Chromecast extension can open the popup because it is whitelisted and can use `chrome.browserAction.openPopup` to do it. (*unless you switch to the Beta channel; on the beta channel any extension can use `chrome.browserAction.openPopup`. This is undocumented, so use it at your own risk.)